# How to operate (fast) on mantissa and exponent part of double or float at c++?

Tags: c++, ieee-754, exponent, numerical-computing, mantissa

I use c++ for computation of various type of special functions (e.g Lambert function, iteration methods for evaluate inversions etc.). In many cases there is an obviously better approach to work with a mantissa and exponent directly.

I found many answers how to extract mantissa and exponent parts, however all of them was just "academic cases with not very effective speed of computation" that are little bit useless for me (my motivation of operate with mantissa and exponent is in improvement of computational speed). Sometimes i need to call some specific function about billion times (very expensive computing) so every saved computational work is fine. And using "frexp" which return mantissa as double is not very fit.

My questions are (for c++ compiler with IEEE 754 floating point):

1) How to read specific bit of mantissa of float/double?

2) How to read whole mantissa into integer/byte of float/double?

3) The same questions as 1), 2) for exponent.

4) The same questions as 1), 2), 3) for write.

With respect that my motivation is faster computation if I work with mantissa or exponent directly. I suppose that there must be a very simple solution.

Comment: Have a look at IEE754 on the web, everything is explained in details. I seriously doubt you really need such a thing...

Comment: There is a very simple, not portable solution. You're going to do odd things, if I may say so. I wouldn't go there. Write efficient code with `float` / `double`, let compiler and the FPU do the rest.

Comment: Here's a well known example of messing with the bits directly, in order to calculate the inverse square root quickly. Perhaps it will inspire your work: http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/

Comment: This shows the bit pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: I recommend using Floating Point Processor or Floating Point hardware assistance to speed up your arithmetic.  Otherwise consider using *Fixed Point* notation.

Comment: Profile.  Profile. Profile.  Optimize the areas that are used most frequently or are the bottlenecks.  Profile. I recently applied some micro-optimizations and gained 7 *nanoseconds*.  In other words, micro-optimizations may not produce as much significance as a change in algorithm.

Comment: Bit level is most likely done in the ALU. Since most CPUs now uses co-processor style FPUs, moving between integer register file and floating point register file is very expensive. Even in the ideal case, what you really get is most likely only speeding up multiply/divide by a power of 2. If your CPU has hardware FPU, then most floating point operations is usually as fast as integer operations, if not, then you really should consider fixed point.

Answer (score 6):

> In many cases there is an obviously better approach to work with a mantissa and exponent directly.

I know that feeling all too well from my signal processing work, but the truth is that exponents and mantissas aren't simply usable as separate numbers; IEEE754 specifies quite some special cases, and offsets etc.

> I suppose that there must be a very simple solution.

Engineering experience tells me: sentences ending with "a simple solution" aren't true, usually.

> "academic cases"

however, is definitely not true (I'll mention an example at the end).

There's very solid real-world usage of optimizations on IEEE754 floats. However, I find that with later x86 processors' abilities to do SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) and the overall fact that floating point is as fast as most "bit-shifty" operations, I generally suspect you're ill-advised to try to do this on a bit level yourself.

Generally, as IEEE754 is a standard, you'll find documentation for how it's stored on your specific architecture everywhere. If you've looked, you should at least have found the wikipedia article explaining how to do 1) and 2) (it's not as static as you seem to think).

What's more important:
**don't** try to be smarter than your compiler. You probably won't be, unless you explicitely know how to vectorize multiple identical operation.

Experiment with your specific compiler's math optimizations. As mentioned, they usually don't do much, nowadays; CPUs aren't slower doing float calculations than they are on integers, necessarily.

I'd rather look at your algorithms and look for potential for optimization there.

Also, while I'm at it, let's pitch VOLK (Vector Optimized Library of Kernels), which is a math library for signal processing, mainly. http://libvolk.org has an overview. Look into the [kernels](https://github.com/gnuradio/volk/tree/master/kernels/volk) that start with 32f, for example [32f_expfast](https://github.com/gnuradio/volk/blob/master/kernels/volk/volk_32f_expfast_32f.h). You will notice there are different implementations, a generic and CPU-optimized ones, different for each SIMD instruction set.

Comment: I agree with argument that c++ compiler is probably clever than me, However, here is a simple example of fast log alg:

int log2_evil(double d) {
    return ((reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long&>(d) >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023;
}

It take about 11 times less computational cost than standart log implementation (if you have no high accuracy req.). 

I am just not sure how mentioned alogritm works exactly. I'd like to avoid unexpected behaviour (not only for well-known log, but for complicated calculations of mine) so that's the reason for my 4 questions.

BTW, thank you for your reference to VOLK!

Comment: @MarekBasovník: try to use VOLK's algorithm. For example, `volk_32f_log2_32f.h` in SSE4.1 implementation takes 118ms for an amount of computations that the generic `math.h`/`log2()` 2916ms took for on my PC. That's a bit more impressive than your "boring" 11x speedup, because its accuracy is much much higher. Though I think I just saw a performance bug in the generic implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the address of the fp value into an `unsigned char*` and treat the resulting pointer as the address of an array that overlays the fp value.

Comment: This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: There is a way of doing the same, that avoid falling afoul of type punning rules in the standard, though: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959

Comment: @Novelocrat the problem is strict aliasing, which doesn't apply here. `char *` and `unsigned char *` are exceptions that are allowed to alias any other type, specifically to inspect object representation. They are the best approaches if you really have to do those low level hacks. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast has a section about the aliasing rules.

Comment: @RaphaelAddile Still undefined behaviour. The machine may be big-endian, little-endian or mixed-endian.

Comment: @MarkWeston Not undefined. The endianness is implementation defined. Which means we don't invoke demons by using it. We just have to look up the implementation documentation (or test endianness programmatically which is easy).

Answer (score -1):

In C or C++ if `x` is an IEEE double then if `L` is a 64 bit long int, the expression

`L = *((long *) &x);`

will allow accessing the bits directly.
If `s` is a byte representing the sign (0 = '+', 1 = '-'), `e` is an integer representing the unbiased exponent, and `f` is a long int representing the fractional bits then

`s = (byte)(L >> 63);`

`e = ((int)(L >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 0x3FF;`

`f = (L & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF);`

(If f is a normalized number, i.e., not 0, denormal, inf, nor NaN, then the last expression should have `0x0010000000000000` added to it to allow for the implicit high-order 1 bit in IEEE double format.)

Repacking the sign, exponent and fraction back into a double is similar:

L = (s << 63) + ((e + 0x3FF) << 52) + (f & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF);

x = *((double *) &L);

The above code generates only a few machine instructions with no subroutine calls on 64-bit machines compiled with 64-bit code.  With 32-bit code there is sometimes a call to do 64-bit arithmetic, but a good compiler will usually generate in-line code.  In either case this approach is very fast.

A similar approach works for C# using `L = bitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(x);`  and `x = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(L);` or exactly as above if unsafe code is allowed.